# Key Value pair filter in an Array[Int,Int]

Tags: scala

In an Array of Integers `index: Array[(Int, Int)]`

```
index = {(1,4),(2,5),(5,2)}
```

How to get the value of corresponding key like `1 -> 4` using filter function in scala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically filtering Array of pairs by first item of pair looks like:

```
index.filter {case (k,v) => k==1}
```

The result of this operation is Array of items matching the criteria. It is not clear from the question what if the index contains several items with key==1? So probably you are looking for find method:

```
index.find {case (k,v) => k==1}
```

which returns Option of matching (key, value)

Answer (score 3):

Since its an Array of tuples you can get the values using _1 and _2.

`index.filter(x => x._1 == 1).map(x => println(x._2))`